# Azure Pipelines : Use Release Gate with HTTP request against Azure Function/Web app behind Azure AD authentication

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I started to use Release Gates on my classic release pipelines to check if my deployed API and Functions Apps are at least well started (could be better but it's a start).

But on my case, I have a function app behind AAD Auth (which is great) but my release gate can no longer request my app.
Did anyone already have this ? I assume that I have to pass a Bearer access token but is it possible from Azure DevOps ?

Comment: Generatlly, the url of azure function is in https format. Can you share how you set up the release gate? Since  there was no response, can you see any error messages in Release process? If you want to add the  Bearer access token, you could add the token in `Headers`:  `Authorization: Bearer <token>`.

Comment: Firstly, I set up a Generic Service connection with Server URL as my API URL "https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net". I did not set the username nor the password/token key as I don't have any at the moment.

On my release gate, I added a "Invoke REST API" task using my generic service connection, GET method and initially (with my other API without AAD auth) nothing in the header. I tried with "Authorization": "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)" but I get a 401. And it's logic because my Azure DevOps system account might not be authorized in my AAD for this ?

Comment: Hi @BastienPerdriau. Since you are using the `Generic Service connection`, are you using the `Invoke REST API` as the Release Gate?  If you directly run the API in Postman or other tools, will it work?  `Bearer $(System.AccessToken)` The variable `System.AccessToken` is used to auth azure devops instead of Azure Function. You need to get the token from azure portal. In Azure Devops, you need to hard-code this token, no variable can directly represent the token used for verification.

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT, I'm indeed using the Invoke REST API task as release gate.
If I run it using Postman, it won't work without the Authorization header.
I understand that the System.AccessToken variable if only related to Azure DevOps internal account so won't work.
Related the "hard-code the token", what would you suggest ? A task which ask AAD for a token ? With what account ? Or do you suggest to set a token value in variable ? But I lasts only one hour.

Comment: Hi @BastienPerdriau. Since the Release gate doesn't run on the Agent job, so we couldn't use the task to get the token. You could manually get the token on Azure Portal and input it in the headers.  To protect the token, you could save the token in the Variable  Group, the `Invoke REST API` Gate could call the variable group. Additional problem: can you maually get the valid token in Azure Portal? And make sure that the api in postman could work fine.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT I understand what you mean but as the token only lasts one hour, I might have to update it each time the release is run ?

Comment: To confirm the token, Is your token from the `AAD -> app registrations`？If not, could you please share the steps to create the token on azure. Then I will try my best to find a workaround

Comment: Yes it's right,I have a AAD app to secure access to my function app.

Comment: Is the token Client secrets, right? This secret could keep at least 1 years. If no, Could you please update the question and share the screenshot about create the token.